# Azure AD with NTLM/Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: windows, azure, ntlm

I'm looking for a way to auto-login a user that's logged in with an Azure AD user account into a web application.

What I've got so far: A web application that uses an Azure OAUTH workflow to login to the application. The user is forwarded to Azure's login page and after a successful login, he will be redirected to the web application with an oauth code that later used to get the user's identity.

Now I've got a new situation: Windows PC are part of a Azure Active Directory and the users all use AD users. Is it possible to use NTLM/Windows Integrated Authentication to auto-login when they open the page.

I looked for a way to enable NTLM/WIA for the OATUH flow to avoid that a user has to re-enter the credentials that he just used to unlock his pc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you'll need to look at Seamless SSO to do this. I'm not an expert on this part of AAD though :/